# Java. TDD. Как проверить в тесте что значение != null

Tags: java, test-driven-development

Есть необходимость проверить что объекту в массиве, изначально имеющему значение null было присвоено значение.

Есть метод подтверждающий что значение null

```
assertThat(result, is(nullValue()));
```

А подскажите аналог с противоположным смыслом тоесть

```
assertThat(result, is( НЕ nullValue()));
```

То есть не важно что в result, главное не null без необходимости уточнять что именно там есть.

Comment: так не прокатит `assertThat(result, !is(nullValue()));`?  вообще вроде проверка на null: `assertThat(null, is(nullValue()));` на не null: `assertThat("a", is(notNullValue()));`

Comment: еще был хелпер `not()`, если память не изменяет

Comment: Можно воспользоваться hamcrest там есть метод notNullValue(), обертка над not() http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/IsNull.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет о `junit` то в нем есть методы:

[public static void assertNotNull(java.lang.Object object)](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertNotNull(java.lang.Object))

и

[public static void assertNull(java.lang.Object object)](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertNull(java.lang.Object))

Воспользоваться можно импортировав пакет `Assert`:

`import static org.junit.Assert.*;`